# Cannot Install anything because of error exit status 2 and error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, google-chrome

Whenever I try to install anything,I am trying to install chrome in particular but it doesnt let me install anything

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_90.0.4430.93-1_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_90.0.4430.93-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_90.0.4430.93-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the error i get everywhere ,i have tried everything ,every solution i can find on the internet

```
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_90.0.4430.93-1_amd64.deb
```

I cant even install from snyaptic or terminal Both give the same error

Please help me I am desperate

Answer (score 1):

You have broken download. Please clean package cache and retry by

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```